# Fibonacci being very strange in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, math, python-3.x, fibonacci

Basically I'm quite new to Python, but ive written a code for the Fibonacci Sequence and it doesn't work, i've compared it online and its pretty much the same but when i write it slightly differently, it works! - But I have no idea why, can anyone shed some light on why it is behaving this way?

This code has been built and tested in the Python 3.3.2 Shell.

Working Code:

```
def fib(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while b < n:
          print(b)
          a, b = b, b + a
```

Non-Working Code:

```
def fib(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    while b < n:
        print(b)
        a = b
        b = b + a
```

I'm completely confused as to why it only works when the variables are grouped together and not when they are separate.

Comment: This question is clearly not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @roippi my question is different to the one asked in that post.

Comment: It's very clearly a dupe.  You don't understand what `a,b = b, b+a` does.

Comment: I'm not a Python expert, but `a=b and b=b+a` effectively results in b being set to twice its original value, which is not what you want.

Comment: [here is a more word-for-word dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15515920/regarding-the-fibonacci-sequence-example-in-pythons-function-tutorial), if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks @roippi , that clears a few things up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe it's in the line `a,b = b,b+a`.

The actual executed version does things a bit differently.  An expanded form would be:

```
c = a
a = b
b = b + c
```

As `b` is incremented by the initial value of `a`, not the adjusted value.

Comment: But i thought the variables are defined the same so why do they behave differently?

Comment: Like veedrac says below, there's an intermediate step here that isn't obvious.  The right side is calculated and stored in temporary space, then finally assigned to the left...

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Yeraze's answer, the actual assignment is closer to

```
# Make the tuple
a_b = (b, b+a)

# Unpack the tuple
a = a_b[0]
b = a_b[1]
```

so it's more obvious why the values are set *and then* assigned.